# How to perform optimization of computing divisors?

Tags: c++, optimization

I've got a task. I must compute all integer divisors of a number and write them to standard output. My program works but in some cases is to slow. Do you know how to perform an optimization? Here's the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    long n;
    scanf("%ld", &n);
    printf("1\n");
    for(long i = 2; i <= int(n/2); i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            printf("%ld\n", i);
    }
    printf("%ld", n);
}
```

Comment: FYI. this type of question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If 2 is a divisor, then I can immediately tell you another divisor. Which one would that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divisors of a natural number come in pairs: one half of the pair is `i <= sqrt(n)`, the other is `(n / i) >= sqrt(n)`. It follows that you can loop up to the square root of `n` instead of `n/2`, then report both `i` and `n/i`.

[Aside: you're using a `long` to represent `n`, but then you cast `n/2` to `int`. On platforms where `sizeof(long) > sizeof(int)`, you're losing precision.]